# Proof of linear independence in Theorem 13.4 of Dummit and Foote

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

**Theorem 13.4 of Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote**: Let $p(x) \in F[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over the field $F$ and let $K = F[x]/(p(x))$. Let $\theta = x \text{ mod} (p(x)) \in K$. Then the elements $$1, \theta, \theta^2, \dots, \theta^{n - 1}$$ are a basis for $K$ as a vector space over $F$, so the degree of the extension is $n$, i.e., $[K : F] = n$. Hence $$k = \{a_0 + a_1\theta + \dots + a_{n - 1}\theta^{n - 1}|a_0, a_1, \dots, a_{n - 1} \in F\}$$ consists of all polynomials of degree $< n$ in $\theta$.

In the proof of the above theorem in the text, the proof of linear independence of the basis vectors $1, x, \dots, x^{n - 1}$ is done by showing that $p(x) \nmid b_0 + b_1x + \dots + b_{n - 1}x^{n - 1}$ since $p(x)$ is of degree $n$, whereas the linear combination of powers of $x$ is of degree $n - 1$. However, what about the case that the degree of the linear combination is $0$, i.e. $b_0 + b_1x + \dots + b_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} = 0$? Since $n|0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Comment: Please do not misspell title words to get around the prohibition on duplicated titles. The fact that "Proof of linear independence" is taken should signal to you that the title is too generic, and you should strive for a title that is more informative and specific as to your query. Misspelling words as you have done makes it more difficult to find your post in the future, which means it will not be useful for other users and it will be a useless addition to the math.stackexchange repository.

Comment: The degree of $q(x):=b_0 + b_1x + \dots + b_{n - 1}x^{n - 1}$ is $\le n-1$. If $q(x)=p(x)m(x)$ for some polynomial $m(x)$, what we get is ***not*** $\deg q=n\deg m$ but $\deg q=n\color{red}+\deg m$ hence $\deg m\le-1$ i.e. $m=0$ (remind $\color{red}{\deg 0=-\infty}$), and $q(x)=0$. So, if $(b_0,\dots,b_{n-1})\ne(0,\dots,0)$ then $p(x)\not\mid q(x)$.

Comment: A polynomial of degree zero is a nonzero constant, Henry.

Comment: The case you are worried about is the case where the polynomial is the zero polynomial, but that's precisely what you are trying to prove – that any polynomial of degree less than $n$ that vanishes is the zero polynomial.